# Reinforcement Learning - only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars - is it data problem?

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to pytorch and even though I was searching for this error I can't seem to understand where axactly I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to run a codewith a model that trades 3 different stocks. My data is a csv file with three columns with closing prices of stocks.

I'm trying to run this part of code

```
env.reset()
# In case you're running this a second time with the same model, delete the gradients
del model.rewards[:]
del model.saved_actions[:]

gamma = 0.9
log_interval = 60

def finish_episode():
    R = 0
    saved_actions = model.saved_actions
    policy_losses = []
    value_losses = []
    rewards = []
    for r in model.rewards[::-1]:
        R = r + (gamma * R)
        rewards.insert(0, R)
    rewards = torch.tensor(rewards)
    
    epsilon = (torch.rand(1) / 1e4) - 5e-5
    # With different architectures, I found the following standardization step sometimes
    # helpful, sometimes unhelpful.
    # rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / (rewards.std(unbiased=False) + epsilon)
    # Alternatively, comment it out and use the following line instead:
    rewards += epsilon
    
    for (log_prob, value), r in zip(saved_actions, rewards):
        reward = torch.tensor(r - value.item()).cuda()
        policy_losses.append(-log_prob * reward)
        value_losses.append(F.smooth_l1_loss(value, torch.tensor([r]).cuda()))
        
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.stack(policy_losses).sum() + torch.stack(value_losses).sum()
    loss = torch.clamp(loss, -1e-5, 1e5)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    del model.rewards[:]
    del model.saved_actions[:]

running_reward = 0
for episode in range(0, 4000):
    state = env.reset()
    reward = 0
    done = False
    msg = None
    while not done:
        action = model.act(state)
        state, reward, done, msg = env.step(action)
        model.rewards.append(reward)
        if done:
            break
    running_reward = running_reward * (1 - 1/log_interval) + reward * (1/log_interval)
    finish_episode()
    # Resetting the hidden state seems unnecessary - it's effectively random from the previous
    # episode anyway, more random than a bunch of zeros.
    # model.reset_hidden()
    if msg["msg"] == "done" and env.portfolio_value() > env.starting_portfolio_value * 1.1 and running_reward > 500:
        print("Early Stopping: " + str(int(reward)))
        break
    if episode % log_interval == 0:
        print("""Episode {}: started at {:.1f}, finished at {:.1f} because {} @ t={}, \
last reward {:.1f}, running reward {:.1f}""".format(episode, env.starting_portfolio_value, \
              env.portfolio_value(), msg["msg"], env.cur_timestep, reward, running_reward))
```

But I'm getting such an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-ce955397be85> in <module>()
     45     msg = None
     46     while not done:
---> 47         action = model.act(state)
     48         state, reward, done, msg = env.step(action)
     49         model.rewards.append(reward)

1 frames
<ipython-input-89-f463539c7fe3> in forward(self, x)
     16 
     17     def forward(self, x):
---> 18         x = torch.tensor(x).cuda()
     19         x = torch.sigmoid(self.input_layer(x))
     20         x = torch.tanh(self.hidden_1(x))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This is the part of code with forward function defined

```
class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(11, 128)
        self.hidden_1 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.hidden_2 = nn.Linear(32,31)
        self.hidden_state = torch.tensor(torch.zeros(2,1,32)).cuda()
        self.rnn = nn.GRU(128, 32, 2)
        self.action_head = nn.Linear(31, 5)
        self.value_head = nn.Linear(31, 1)
        self.saved_actions = []
        self.rewards = []

    def reset_hidden(self):
        self.hidden_state = torch.tensor(torch.zeros(2,1,32)).cuda()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.tensor(x).cuda()
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.input_layer(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.hidden_1(x))
        x, self.hidden_state = self.rnn(x.view(1,-1,128), self.hidden_state.data)
        x = F.relu(self.hidden_2(x.squeeze()))
        action_scores = self.action_head(x)
        state_values = self.value_head(x)
        return F.softmax(action_scores, dim=-1), state_values
    
    def act(self, state):
        probs, state_value = self.forward(state)
        m = Categorical(probs)
        action = m.sample()
        if action == 1 and env.state[0] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda()
        if action == 4 and env.state[1] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda()
        if action == 6 and env.state[2] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda()
        self.saved_actions.append((m.log_prob(action), state_value))
        return action.item()
```

Can you please direct me where I should make changes? Is it the data I'm feeding my model with, or something different?

Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `state = env.reset()` to:

- `action = model.act(state)`
- `probs, state_value = self.forward(state)`
- `x = torch.tensor(x).cuda()`

And hence torch is throwing an error. It expects a numeric or array type input.

Comment: I've been trying to correct it using `type(torch.DoubleTensor) ` on state but it gives me an error. Any chance you know how to fix this? I mean which part I need to change. I'm using code from this github: https://github.com/tomgrek/RL-stocktrading/blob/master/Finance%20final.ipynb Thank you for your answer.